# Bcrypt class generating different hashes?

Tags: php, bcrypt

This is absolutely driving me crazy.

When registering an account I store the output of generateHash in the database.

I then generateHash again using the same $pattern when people try to log in.

However, the class generates a different hash. Even though I used the same pattern and password. This seems illogical.

```
class class_bcrypt
{   
    public function generateHash($pattern, $password)
    {
        //generate salt
        $salt = '$2y$13$';
        $salt = $salt . md5(strtolower($pattern));

        //generate hash
        $hash = crypt($password, $salt);
        $hash = substr($hash, 29);
        return $hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/zpWqu9 - not reproducible

Comment: could it be a different character set or something in database? I'm using latin1_swedish_ci and the registration takes from $_POST

Comment: [Please stop trying to salt and hash your passwords yourself](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Or when not on php 5.5 use https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat. You're welcome :-)

Comment: This works fine for me, your inputs seem to be what's changing.

Comment: @Amy Neville: "could it be a different character set or something in database" -- you said "I used the same pattern and password". Triple check they are actually the same

Comment: In that case use the provided compatibility library to hash your passwords. It's really easy to use, secure and is a userland implementation of the native PHP password API.

Comment: @PeeHaa - oh is that then forwards compatible with where php is going then?

Comment: Exactly. Once you upgrade to php5.5+ it will automatically start using that without you having to make any chances to your code.